# Type mismatch on active pattern with ReadOnlySpan<char> parameters and (expected) implicit argument conversion

Tags: string, performance, f#, active-pattern

I am confused as to why this bit of F# code fails to compile:

```
open System

[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Al =

    [<return: Struct>]
    let inline (|EquivalentName|_|) (name1: string) (name2: string) : unit voption = 
        ValueNone // irrelevant

    [<return: Struct>]
    let inline (|EquivalentNameSpans|_|) (name1: ReadOnlySpan<char>) (name2: ReadOnlySpan<char>) : unit voption = 
        ValueNone // irrelevant

    let inline EquivalentNameSpans' (name1: ReadOnlySpan<char>, name2: ReadOnlySpan<char>) : unit voption = 
        ValueNone // irrelevant
        
let test() =
    // Ok
    match "foo" with
    | Al.EquivalentName "foo" -> ()
    | _ -> ()
    
    // Ok
    match "foo".AsSpan() with
    | Al.EquivalentNameSpans "foo" -> () // Warning 3391 on second "foo" literal
    | _ -> ()
    
    // Ok
    match "foo" : ReadOnlySpan<char> with
    | Al.EquivalentNameSpans "foo" -> () // Warning 3391 on both "foo" literals
    | _ -> ()
    
    // Ok
    match Al.EquivalentNameSpans'("foo", "foo") with
    | ValueNone -> ()
    | ValueSome _ -> ()
    
    //error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    //    'string -> 'a voption'    
    //but given a
    //    'ReadOnlySpan<char> -> unit voption'    
    //The type 'string' does not match the type 'ReadOnlySpan<char>'
    //error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    //    'string -> 'a voption'    
    //but given a
    //    'ReadOnlySpan<char> -> unit voption'    
    //The type 'string' does not match the type 'ReadOnlySpan<char>'
    match "foo" with
    | Al.EquivalentNameSpans "foo" -> () // error on this line
    | _ -> ()
```

Generally, the F# compiler seems perfectly able to implicitly convert `string` to `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, albeit with a warning, but here, in the context of an active pattern, it fails to convert - what gives?

Open in [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Comment: I agree this is puzzling. Could be a corner-case that the compiler doesn't yet handle. You might want to open an issue in GitHub.